# Customizing the look and feel of a Kendo UI PanelBar

Tags: kendo-ui

I need to develop an application where Kendo's `PanelBar` is one of the main elements, but I have some layout requirements.

- A *main header* (canonical panel text)
- A *sub header* (additional text you can find in the panel header)
- A dynamic image (on the right, just before the dropdown marker)

Example:

[image]

I'm wondering if there's a native and general way of customizing the look and feel of the Kendo PanelBar (and other) using kendo templates.

I know that this is possible for some components like `kendoMobileListView` or other, but I don't find documentation about panels (or if this a feature generally applicable to all Kendo widgets).

If not: what is the best an repeatable approach for doing this without relying on old-school creation events?

Comment: I don't think this is something I can move to the theme. text and displayed image are strongly coupled to my application logic. That's why I'm looking for template support (or similar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/poojadhanani/Fj3vC/110/) - Adjust margin as per your image height x width using.

```js
$("#panelbar-images").kendoPanelBar({
    dataSource: [
        {
            text: "<span class='k-text'>Baseball</span><span  class='k-sub-text'> SubHeader</span>",
            encoded: false,
            imageUrl: "http://demos.kendoui.com/content/shared/icons/sports/baseball.png",
            items: [
                { text: "Top News", imageUrl: "http://demos.kendoui.com/content/shared/icons/16/star.png" },
                { text: "Photo Galleries", imageUrl: "http://demos.kendoui.com/content/shared/icons/16/photo.png" },
                { text: "Videos Records", imageUrl: "http://demos.kendoui.com/content/shared/icons/16/video.png" },
                { text: "Radio Records", imageUrl: "http://demos.kendoui.com/content/shared/icons/16/speaker.png" }
            ]
        },
        {
            text: "Golf", imageUrl: "http://demos.kendoui.com/content/shared/icons/sports/golf.png",
            items: [
                { text: "Top News", imageUrl: "http://demos.kendoui.com/content/shared/icons/16/star.png" },
                { text: "Photo Galleries", imageUrl: "http://demos.kendoui.com/content/shared/icons/16/photo.png" },
                { text: "Videos Records", imageUrl: "http://demos.kendoui.com/content/shared/icons/16/video.png" },
                { text: "Radio Records", imageUrl: "http://demos.kendoui.com/content/shared/icons/16/speaker.png" }
            ]
        },
        {
            text: "Swimming", imageUrl: "http://demos.kendoui.com/content/shared/icons/sports/swimming.png",
            items: [
                { text: "Top News", imageUrl: "http://demos.kendoui.com/content/shared/icons/16/star.png" },
                { text: "Photo Galleries", imageUrl: "http://demos.kendoui.com/content/shared/icons/16/photo.png" }
            ]
        },
        {
            text: "Snowboarding", imageUrl: "http://demos.kendoui.com/content/shared/icons/sports/snowboarding.png",
            items: [
                { text: "Photo Galleries", imageUrl: "http://demos.kendoui.com/content/shared/icons/16/photo.png" },
                { text: "Videos Records", imageUrl: "http://demos.kendoui.com/content/shared/icons/16/video.png" }
            ]
        }
    ]
});
```

```css
.k-text{  
    float: left; 
    margin-right:10%;
     font-size:20px;
}
.k-sub-text{
  float: left;
  margin-right:10%;
 }
.k-panelbar img.k-image{ 
   float: none;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2012.1.515/styles/kendo.common.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2012.1.515/styles/kendo.blueopal.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.112/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>



<div id="panelbar-images"></div>
```

Comment: That's amazing, thanks. So seems that the key (at least in that case) is the `dataSource`.
NB: the jsfiddle link at the top is broken.